# JPA - Hibernate : Map several tables on one column of another

Tags: java, jpa, hibernate-mapping

Conserider following table structure

```
country
=======
id
code
name_id

label
======
id
code
label_value_id

translations
=============
id
ref_id
language
value
```

Now I need to find a JPA mapping to map `country:name_id` and `label:label_value_id` to translations `ref_id`.  I've been googling after the right english term to explain this situation but am coming up empty on decent hits.  So the database can hold records as in this example

```
country
id: 1, code: BE, name_id: 30

label
id: 1, code: LABELA, label_value_id: 31

translations
id: 1, ref_id: 30, language: EN, value: BELGIUM
id: 2, ref_id: 30, language: NL, value: BELGIE
id: 3, ref_id: 31, language: EN, value: ALPHA_A
id: 4, ref_id: 31, language: NL, value: ALFA_A
```

In Java I have the 3 classes

Country, Label and Translation where I will have `@OneToMany` relations on Country and Label to Translation that both should map on `ref_id` but I have no idea how to write my `@OneToMany` code to achieve this.  Any hints in the right direction would be very appreciated, a solution or manual

=====

Update 2013-03-23

As stated by Joop, using a discriminator is the sollution BUT it didn't work out of the box.  I was forced to use a hibernate annotation  @DiscriminatorOptions(force=true).  If you don't add it , hibernate totally ignores the Discriminator in it's SQL queries when fetching the needed collections.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "testtranslations")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DTYPE", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)
public class TestTranslation extends DomainObject {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6211853644196769521L;

    private long id;
    private String language;
    private String value;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="testtranslations_seq_gen") 
    @SequenceGenerator(name="testtranslations_seq_gen", sequenceName="TESTTRANSLATIONS_SEQ") 
    @Column(name="testtranslation_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="language", length=3, nullable=false)
    public String getLanguage() {
        return language;
    }

    @Column(name="value")
    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setLanguage(String language) {
        this.language = language;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "testcountries")
public class TestCountry extends DomainObject {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9207081478447113501L;

    private long id;
    private String code;
    private List<NameTranslation> name;
    private List<DescriptionTranslation> description;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="testcountries_seq_gen") 
    @SequenceGenerator(name="testcountries_seq_gen", sequenceName="TESTCOUNTRIES_SEQ") 
    @Column(name="country_id")
    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name="iso_code", length=3, nullable=false)
    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="refId")
    public List<NameTranslation> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="refId")
    public List<DescriptionTranslation> getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public void setName(List<NameTranslation> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setDescription(List<DescriptionTranslation> description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("NAMETRANSLATION")
public class NameTranslation extends TestTranslation {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7197732491071768673L;

    private TestCountry refId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "refId", nullable=false)
    public TestCountry getRefId() {
        return refId;
    }

    public void setRefId(TestCountry refId) {
        this.refId = refId;
    }   
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("DESCTRANSLATION")
public class DescriptionTranslation extends TestTranslation {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -4128287237786410515L;

    private TestCountry refId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "refId", nullable=false)
    public TestCountry getRefId() {
        return refId;
    }

    public void setRefId(TestCountry refId) {
        this.refId = refId;
    }   
}
```

I made the needed hibernate mappings and wrote a DbUnit test to load a TestCountry by id with following data

```
<TESTCOUNTRIES COUNTRY_ID="1" VERSION="0" ISO_CODE="BE" />  
<TESTTRANSLATIONS TESTTRANSLATION_ID="1" VERSION="0" LANGUAGE="EN" VALUE="Belgium" REFID="1" DTYPE="NAMETRANSLATION" />
<TESTTRANSLATIONS TESTTRANSLATION_ID="2" VERSION="0" LANGUAGE="NL" VALUE="Belgie" REFID="1" DTYPE="NAMETRANSLATION" />
<TESTTRANSLATIONS TESTTRANSLATION_ID="3" VERSION="0" LANGUAGE="EN" VALUE="BelgiumDesc" REFID="1" DTYPE="DESCTRANSLATION" />
<TESTTRANSLATIONS TESTTRANSLATION_ID="4" VERSION="0" LANGUAGE="NL" VALUE="BelgieDesc" REFID="1" DTYPE="DESCTRANSLATION" />
```

I hope this will help other people in the future, I'm just sad there isn't a JPA sollution and I had to be forced to use a hibernate annotation.

Comment: Are you saying your refid column can refer to either a country name_id or label label_value_id? How do you differentiate between the two?

Comment: How about creating a parent class for `country` and `label` and `translations` will hold reference to that parent class?

Comment: It might be a good thing to precise why you would want to do that as it seems a discutable design.

Comment: Are you saying that `translations:ref_id` can refer to either `country:name_id` OR `label:label_value_id`?

Comment: I'll try to explain: The concept would be that a record country has several translations for it's "human readable name".  Same for label.  The dba wants to put all those translations in one table translations.  Now I have the challenge to map 2 tables to the one and the same table column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit difficult as you have a foreign key for either table 1 or table 2.

There does exist a **discriminator** concept in JPA, for table inheritance. One then derives two tables from a common abstract table, and has different discriminator fields. An [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0355__JPA/DiscriminatorColumnAndDiscriminatorValue.htm). This works a bit differently though.

*P.S. look for a better example using search keys discriminatorValue and discriminatorColumn.*

Comment: If I would use Inheritance to inherit Country and Label from Translation, wouldn't all the records of Country and Label be in the same table as well ?  I would ofcourse have a DTYPE column telling what kind of record it is Country or Label but all data would be in one table wouldn't it ?  I don't think my DBA would love that idea :(

Comment: No, they stay separate tables - when you do not do `@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)`,

Comment: Thnx Joop I'll take this to the next technical meeting and see if they go for it

Comment: It worked out in the end , I've updated my question with the sollution I used , thnx